# Why smaller is faster?

Tags: power

I have a question regarding to hardware signal. There is a rule says *["] [Smaller is faster.](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/CACHE/small_fast.html) [."]*, which in the link states that

1. > In high-speed machines, **signal propagation** is a ***major cause*** of delay;

   Q: **I don't believe this.** I think this is just academia explanation. Or is there any diagram can show the details of this? e.g. the x-axis is number of registers/memory unit and the y-axis is the delay/time
   <sub>Actually you may but you don't have to answer my Q1</sub>
2. > In most technologies we can obtain smaller memories that are faster than larger memories. This is primarily because the designer can use **more power** per memory cell in a smaller design;

   Q: Why more power will make signal faster? Isn't that the speed of current the same regarding to the same medium?

Comment: I feel like it has something to do with capacitance, among other things; if you scale down a capacitor equally in all dimensions, \$A\$ decreases quadratically and \$d\$ decreases linearly, meaning that \$C\$, which is proportional to \$\frac{A}{d}\$, decreases linearly..

Comment: Consider the Dk of silicon is something like 10 or 12 (IIRC) and in really fast logic we care about picoseconds of delay, if you want to route a signal across a whole chip (3-10mm, say), the speed of light delay really is significant. Whether it's the dominant limit on switching frequencies, I'm not sure.

Comment: Silicon Dk = 11.7 according to the Ioffe Institute...glad I didn't misremember that number too badly.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Great, thank you then I must be wrong in my 1, according to your comment.

Comment: Note silicon dioxide Dk is only ~3.8, so speed of light on upper metal layers is better than right against the silicon.

Comment: @ThePhoton: For dk you mean [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_permittivity)?

Comment: Yes, it's a common symbol for dielectric constant.

Comment: Mobility of charges, the speed of hole/electron movement in doped silicon, sets a speed limit thru devices. 10X smaller devices thus have 10X shorter delays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your Q2, keep in mind that this is in the context of logic gates, which in CMOS logic are switched by driving the gate of a MOSFET.  MOSFET gates behave like small capacitors.  To change the state of these gates, i.e. to charge or discharge the capacitor, you need to apply a current to it.  The time it takes to charge or discharge will depend on the magnitude of the current applied, so more power gets you faster switching.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you! Every time I read textbook it made me felt like I'm fooled...

Comment: The change of state also involves resistance of connecting wire (RC anyone?) That's one reason why smaller is faster - shorter wire has less resistance. This is the same reason why silicon manufacturers switched for more conductive copper interconnect instead of aluminum.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Didn't know they were using copper now, neat!

Comment: @Hearth, yes, about for 15 years already, since 130nm process, Intel is using copper interconnect and low-K dielectric, Pentium-4/Northwood, https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee311/NOTES/Interconnect%20Cu%20Slides.pdf